# property not updating in object when page is posted

Tags: php, oop

I have set a property in a constructor like so

```
function __construct()
{

$this->count = count(@$_SESSION['filearray']); //count how many files in array
}
```

and using it in condition statements `if($this->count > 10) //then do something`

but it appears the count isn't being updated when I use another method of injecting values into this 'filearray' until I refresh the page.

am I doing something wrong? I thought that my constructor would detect a change had been made in the session and whenever I call $this->count I would get the current count value but it seems to be 1 step behind until I refresh the page.

If this is all vague I can include my form page that has all the method calls, but this is the jist of my question, why is my property not updating and how do I fix it :)

TIA

Comment: Please be aware that using the `@` operator is bad form and a performance hit.  Try `array_key_exists('filearray', $_SESSION) && is_array($_SESSION['filearray']) ? count($_SESSION['filearray']) : 0;` -- it's more verbose, but it's free of the warnings and notices that the `@` operator hides.

Comment: Thanks for the tip Charles, I try my best to not use '@' but sometimes I be lazy for the scale of the work I'm doing. But good to know anyways, someone needs to make a php tricks manual :) /me heads back to google

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$this->count` won't automatically be updated with the count every time you add or subtract from the filearray session. Constructors are only invoked upon instantiation of the class or when called directly.

You can achieve this sort of functionality using a getter.

```
class myClass {
  public function getCount() {
    return count(@$_SESSION['filearray']);
  }
}

$_SESSION['filearray'] = array('bar');
$foo = new myClass();
echo $foo->getCount(); // 1
```

Or by using the [`__get()` magic-method](https://www.php.net/__get):

```
class myClass {

  public function __get($property_name) {
    if ($property_name == 'count') {
      return count(@$_SESSION['filearray']);
    }
  }
}

$_SESSION['filearray'] = array('bar');
$foo = new myClass();
echo $foo->count; // 1
```

Or a combination of the two:

```
class myClass {

  private $_count;

  public function __get($property_name) {
    if ($property_name == 'count') {
      return $this->_getCount();
    }
  }

  private function _getCount() {
    return $this->_count = count(@$_SESSION['filearray']);
  }
}

$_SESSION['filearray'] = array('bar');
$foo = new myClass();
echo $foo->count; // 1
```

Comment: thanks that did the trick mate, this is only my 2nd class I've written by myself so still understanding OOP :)